# Embedded software questions?

Tags: discussion

Is "Electrical Engineering" the right place for embedded software/firmware development questions?

We get questions here (and did on "Chiphacker" and "Electronic Design") about embedded software tools and techniques.

Do they still belong here?

stackoverflow.com deals with low level programming topics, but seems to cater less well to firmware engineers who sit on the software/hardware divide.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

<strike>I think that stackoverflow question about embedded software/firmware should migrate to E&R.</strike>

---

Edit:
I met chiphacker because I asked a question about embedded software in StackOverflow and someone recommended me it. And this community is much better for me.

Comment: agreed. This is a major part of it.

Comment: Yourself and O engenheiro. Unless I am misunderstanding, you said the same thing.

Comment: @Joby - This answer posits "Yes" for asking firmware questions. It also proposes that SO questions about firmware: [`firmware`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firmware) (47 questions) and [`embedded`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) (~1,000 questions) be moved here. I would vote 'yes' for their appropriateness here, but I don't know about migrating questions from SO.

Comment: @Joby you're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but questions about software in general (e.g. how to do a sort) that happen to be on an embedded target shouldn't be.