# appropriate tags rejected

Tags: discussion

I studied [unnecessary tags](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/are-these-tags-really-unnecessary), but my tags were not that much in appropriate. yet they were rejected.
[image: rejected]
 I meant that Eagle is mostly used for PCB so why is PCB or PCB-design tag inappropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's not actually about those topics. If you look at the question, it is purely about using the software.

Comment: but its related to PCB too

Comment: @JigarGandhi If I'm looking for PCB layout questions, I don't want to find questions about using Eagle. Those tags really have nothing to do at all with the question.

Comment: I was the one who had rejected the edit.  Reason: the question is purely about software usage on a particular OS.  In fact, PCB was not even mentioned in the question.  The O.P. might as well have been working on a schematic, for all we know.  The proposed tag edit was not appropriate.