# Are questions on large scale civil electrical engineering on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask why it takes years to build a single large grid transformer. Is a question like that on-topic? If it's not on-topic here, would it be on-topic on a different stack?

Comment: This is the best fitted site for such questions within Stack Exchange. For example there's been the occasional high voltage guru posting here in the past.

Comment: Seem on topic to me. I don't know how custom  each large grid transformer is, but if each one is designed from the ground up and tooled specifically to build that one, I wouldn't be surprised if it took a few years after having seeing things designed then produced/machined.

Comment: related: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/are-power-electrical-engineering-questions-on-topic-for-ee-se-if-so-should-thi

Answer (score 6):

The question is not off topic but YMMV because there are few power\industrial engineers here. You may not get the best answers

Answer (score 5):

I would *think so*; this stack *is* "Electrical Engineering", not "Electr*onics* Engineering."

Like all aspects of electrical/electronics, large-scale-grid is its own separate "local cluster" in the "electricity galaxy." I've seen a few such questions answered. But the quality of the answers totally depends on which experts (if any) happen to see the question. The more obscure and field-specific the question, the less chance anybody else will know about it.

That said, folks here are quite intelligent. Very rarely is this stack totally clueless about anything ranging from "vacuum nanotubes" to beer...

Comment: It's electrical engineering but the topics are mostly about "a specific electronic design problem" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic That being said we do most any electrical design question, but most people are circuit designers so if you do post a question about power electronics or the grid, you may not get a timely answer or an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that it is on-topic here, though I suspect better answers might come from engineering.stackexchange.com since the issues involved are not so much about the electrical properties of substation transformers but about the process of specification, procurement, and manufacturing of large-scale unique-design equipment.

FWIW, I would also be interested in seeing more questions and answers within this realm of EE on this stack.  Although electronics is a hobby since adolescence, my profession is EE within environmental public infrastructure (i.e. water, wastewater, solid waste).